# AWS CLI assume-role followed by other commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I would like to do something like

```
aws sts assume-role ... 
aws s3 ... --profile (assumed role from above command)
```

Is there a good way to get the output of `assume-role` in a format that can be readily consumed into subsequent AWS CLI commands?

Comment: This could be useful (requires jq):https://gist.githubusercontent.com/riponbanik/c0a7eed281f4861f25f4b6556cd8b0fa/raw/e4b4b877827fa4ce3ea277a4cb5d54760da6e692/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @Christian if you make that an answer I can accept it.   Piping output through `jq` seems like the best option.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of an AWS-provided mechanism to take the output of `aws sts assume-role` and persist it either into your environment variables or as a profile in `~/.aws/credentials`.

You can, however, simply assume the role each and every time you invoke the awscli. This will generate new credentials each time, but that's not a problem in my experience. For example, in `~/.aws/config`:

```
[profile qa]
region = us-east-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/s3-ec2-readonly
source_profile=wrschneider
```

And in `~/.aws/credentials`:

```
[wrschneider]
aws_access_key_id = abc
aws_secret_access_key = xyz
```

Then you can invoke with the assumed role like this:

- `aws s3 ls --profile qa`
- `aws ec2 describe-instances --profile qa`

Or simply set/export `AWS_PROFILE=qa` in your environment and run:

- `aws s3 ls`
- `aws ec2 describe-instances`

If you don't like that option, there are a few third-party options that will push the STS credentials into your environment:

- [aws-sts-assumerole](https://github.com/rik2803/aws-sts-assumerole)
- [awssudo](https://underthehood.meltwater.com/blog/2018/01/22/assuming-roles-in-aws-with-sudo-like-agility/)
- [shell script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/riponbanik/c0a7eed281f4861f25f4b6556cd8b0fa/raw/e4b4b877827fa4ce3ea277a4cb5d54760da6e692/gistfile1.txt) as suggested by @Christian